# Change from Localhost to server IP doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, deployment

I am currently deploying a laravel app to a ubuntu VM, after lots of headache it finally worked and I can see the website in 127.0.0.1:8000 after running `php artisan serve` ! :)

However, I tried changing the address from localhost to the IP of the server.

my ´/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
132.231.36.101 laravel.dev
127.0.1.1 lehner-grund01
```

I also tried removing the 127... address as a whole but it didn't change anything.

In my `.env` file I have this:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=<my_key>
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://132.231.36.101
```

I tried changing the IP in the `ServeCommand.php` file as well - didn't work either.

My `conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` looks like this:

NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot grup1/project/tose-gruppe-1/public

    <Directory /home/user/projects/laravel_project/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried doing it "manually" when running `php artisan serve` to add host like this:

`php artisan serve --host=<my_ip> --port`

Its the first time I deploy something on an ubuntu machine and I am done haha. Tried for seven hours now, any help appreciated!

Edit:
Message when using status command:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-05 21:43:04 UTC; 1h 59min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 47274 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 48577 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 47278 (apache2)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 4575)
     Memory: 17.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─47278 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48581 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48582 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48583 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48584 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48585 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─48820 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─48826 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 05 21:43:04 lehner-tse01 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 05 21:43:04 lehner-tse01 apachectl[47277]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/tose-gruppe-1/public] does not exist
Jan 05 21:43:04 lehner-tse01 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 05 22:03:58 lehner-tse01 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 05 22:03:58 lehner-tse01 apachectl[48580]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/tose-gruppe-1/public] does not exist
Jan 05 22:03:58 lehner-tse01 apachectl[48580]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabl>
Jan 05 22:03:58 lehner-tse01 apachectl[48580]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/grup1/project/tose-gruppe-1/public] does not exist
Jan 05 22:03:58 lehner-tse01 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

i don't get why the document root directory is wrong, it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

APP_URL=http://132.231.36.101 does not have to be changed to a public adress since when you forward port 80 to your server it automatically redirects to your server. meaning it goes to the localhost. no public adress needed for that

Comment: what should be there instead then? And I just realized the localhost on the server doesn't work either, I had it running on my laptop and that was what worked. fuck my life

Comment: `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: but check if the server is enabled at all by executing `sudo service apache2 status`

Comment: I get this back, I edit the question

Comment: yes so that means that its online, but have you edited the APP_URL ?

Comment: yes I have! :) thanks for the tipp But the error in the error message says it cant find my Document root, that's pretty bad isn't it?

Comment: edit /etc/hosts to: `127.0.0.1 laravel.dev` (when entering laravel.dev in url you go to localhost) and put `APP_URL=http://localhost` also why does your virtual host have 2 routes?

Comment: I changed it, tried artisan serve but didn't work either. Where is the second route in my virtual host file?

Comment: you should not visit it via artisan serve but rather the original localhost url, also here: `DocumentRoot grup1/project/tose-gruppe-1/public`
    `<Directory /home/user/projects/laravel_project/public/>`

Comment: how can I avoid using artisan serve? don't I need to use it to start the laravel application? 

Ah yes you are correct! which one can I delete ?

Comment: delete the one that does not go to your project or edit. but no you dont "start" a laravel application since its just a website that runs on apache2 and since apache2 has started, the application has started aswell. artisan serve is for when you do not use apache.

Comment: that makes sense yeah, sorry for my utterly dumb questions. My head is done for today. I now didn't use artisan serve and just put in the server ip in the browser and got this error message: 
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at 132.231.36.101 Port 80

Comment: since it says its a error from a server we can say that the routes are wrong.

Comment: Yeah I am googling a lot right now and I sometime read that the routes in my web.php file may all be wrong? Is this possible? I just wanna cry lol

Comment: nah then you would be looking at a laravel error

Comment: GOD BLESS! :D I now moved to just completely uninstall and reinstall apache2 and clone the repository from GitHub again. I did so many things during the day that I figured it would be better to start clean again. I hope it works now, I appreciate you taking so much time off your day to help me here! Linux is a lot to get my head around